# Is there a way to destructure nested objects by grouping

Tags: javascript, reactjs, destructuring

I am trying to destructure a nested object, I can do something like below to get calories and carbohydrates

```
const { calories } = action.payload
const { quantity: carbohydrates } = action.payload.totalNutrients.CHOCDF
```

from the object whose picture I have below

[image]

but to get my other items such as fat, protein, fiber, etc... Would I just continue to do it the way I am doing it or is there an easier way to restructure multiple needed items?

Just for clarification, I am just trying to do this a better way:

```
const { calories } = action.payload
const { quantity: carbohydrates } = action.payload.totalNutrients.CHOCDF
const { quantity: fat } = action.payload.totalNutrients.FAT
const { quantity: fiber } = action.payload.totalNutrients.FIBTG
const { quantity: protein } = action.payload.totalNutrients.PROCNT
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to destructure (while assigning to new variable names) everything all at once like this:

```js
// approximation of the data you are working with

const action = {
  payload: {
    calories: 55,
    totalNutrients: {
      CHOCDF: {
        quantity: 8.52
      },
      CHOLE: {
        quantity: 0
      }
    }
  }
};

const {
  calories,
  totalNutrients: {
    CHOCDF: {
      quantity: carbohydratesQuantity
    },
    CHOLE: {
      quantity: cholesterolQuantity
    }
  }
} = action.payload;

console.log({
  calories,
  carbohydratesQuantity,
  cholesterolQuantity
});
```

---

If you want the whole object instead of just their quantity property, you could do:

```js
const action = {
  payload: {
    calories: 55,
    totalNutrients: {
      CHOCDF: {
        quantity: 8.52,
        label: "Carbs",
        unit: "g"
      },
      CHOLE: {
        quantity: 0,
        label: "Cholesterol",
        unit: "mg"
      }
    }
  }
};

const {
  calories,
  totalNutrients: {
    CHOCDF: carbohydrates,
    CHOLE: cholesterol
  }
} = action.payload;

console.log({
  calories,
  carbohydrates,
  cholesterol
});
```

---

```js
const action = {
  payload: {
    calories: 55,
    totalNutrients: {
      CHOCDF: {
        quantity: 8.52,
        label: "Carbs",
        unit: "g"
      },
      CHOLE: {
        quantity: 0,
        label: "Cholesterol",
        unit: "mg"
      },
      FAT: {
        quantity: 10,
        label: "Fat",
        unit: "g"
      },
      FIBTG: {
        quantity: 0.348,
        label: "Fiber",
        unit: "g"
      },
      PROCNT: {
        quantity: 0.6,
        label: "Protein",
        unit: "g"
      }
    }
  }
};

const {
  calories,
  totalNutrients: {
    CHOCDF: {
      quantity: carbohydrates
    },
    CHOLE: {
      quantity: cholesterol
    },
    FAT: {
      quantity: fat
    },
    FIBTG: {
      quantity: fiber
    },
    PROCNT: {
      quantity: protein
    }
  }
} = action.payload;

console.log({
  calories,
  carbohydrates,
  cholesterol,
  fat,
  fiber,
  protein
});
```

---

There are some good examples here at MDNs page on [Destructuring_assignment under Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring). I recommend that you spend some time reading through this page.

Here's a [codepen example](https://codepen.io/k-sav/pen/MWKzezx) for you to fork and experiment with.

Comment: Sorry, having a bit of hard time understanding, so to summarize I just want the values of totalNutrients object, using the colon I will rename CHOCDF to carbohydrates, FAT to fat, PROCNT to protein, all of whose values are coming from quantity.

Comment: I am not sure why we would destructure the payload, because if I have to type all of that then just doing something like what I did above seems like less work.

Comment: Right, no, I am solely looking for the quantity to be stored not the whole object

Comment: the value in quantity will be the value of carbohydrate
the value in quantity will be the value of protein, etc...

Comment: The first example destructures the quantity properties , doesn't it?

Comment: Sorry, it could be me not fully grasping what you're saying, so I edited the portion with an example of what I am trying to do in a better fashion

Comment: Yes the first example does the same thing. We are just using different variable names. I have chosen `carbohydratesQuantity` because it more clearly describes what the variable represents.

Comment: Totally understand now, you were just writing the object out before doing the destructuring, that confused me...thanks it took a minute for that to register.

Comment: Oh yeah. Just needed an approximation of the data you were working with, so we could have a working example.